# Access map overlays from class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class that needs to access the list of overlays on a map view from a  view controller.

normally on that view controller I can use

```
mapPath *crumbsOverlays = (mapPath *)(self.mapView.overlays);
```

How would I do this from another class object?

Comment: If you want something from mapView then you need a reference to a mapView object. And if you do have a ref. then you have already shown how to get overlays. am I missing something? Could you please rephrase your question. Thanks.

Comment: The code example was on the view controller that did have a reference.  However, inside another class how could I get that ref?

Comment: "The Another class" can have a method which gets the ref via argument. Is this another class is made by you then you can always pass object into it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly, the answer to "How do I access Thing A from Thing B?" is "Give Thing B a means to access Thing A." This is intentionally vague, because there are a huge array of possible implementations.

One concrete possibility here: Put a method on the view controller that does that and give the class a reference to the view controller.

Comment: Would I create a new instance of the view controller from the utility class?

Comment: @jdross: You would not, because a newly created view controller won't have the connections that the existing view controller does. You would have an object that knows about both of them pass a reference to the existing one.

Comment: The method I need to access it from is in - (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)context    Would I need to override this?